# Correct location of angular app index.html file in .NET Core project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, routes

I would like to get some advice on the correct structure of my AngularJS app.

This is the current structure of my project within the root directory:

[image]

As you can see, my `index.html` is inside a sub-directory `www`.

The problem is that when I deploy my app to my server, the `www` is included in the URL so that my URLs look like this: `www.myWebsite.com/www/home` instead of like this: `www.myWebsite.com/home`.

I've seen several projects with the same structure (where index.html is not within the root directory) but not having the same issue with the URLs.

Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on how your project is structured. Usually angular projects generate a "bundle" (a kind of binary), and that bundle is what is deployed to the server. If this is the case, it doesn't matter much where your `index.html` is, what actually matters is where your "bundler" places the `index.html` in the bundle and where you place your bundle at the server.

Comment: @acdcjunior Is this bundle automatically generated or is a configuration required? Because right now I just upload my raw files to the server. And how do I know where this bundle is placed at the server?

Comment: I think if you were using bundles, you would know. So, your deployment procedure is just placing the whole project folder at the server? Apart from the URL, does it work perfectly?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, I sort of just copy and paste all the files at the server. The only other problem that I have noticed is that all the directive templates that I referenced using `templateUrl` are also not retrieved. But apart from that everything else is working fine. I can navigate the website and see contents.

Comment: During development, how do you do it? Do the directives work then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a standard: How about using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)? After you install it run `ng new myapp` and then you will have a standard Angular application in the myapp directory.

Comment: I am using Angular 1.6. Does Angular CLI work with this version of Angular?

Comment: I do not think so. There are completely different sites (and stackoverflow tags) for AngularJS and Angular 2~. If you want the Angular JS folks to have a look you may want to update your questions tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you could handle this. And it really depends on your workflow. I would tell you that when you deploy your application into a live environment that you would only need to deploy the `www` subdirectory.

It also looks like you're using your own build process with gulp rather than the common tool, the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), which I would advise you looking it. The bundle/`dist` folder it will produce for you will have everything built and working for you (which should address the issue with the directives you have).

You did mention though that you're just copying and pasting files into a server... Do you mind me asking what your deploy environment is like?

Comment: I am not sure how you want me to describe the deploy environment but I am trying to deploy my website to a hosting website called x10hosting.com. I use FileZilla to transfer my files to the server.